# Font not working on Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari

Tags: html, css

I have created a popup kind of `div` using css. Here is my code.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700);
.popups-right {
    background: #f57b20 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    right: -120px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.popups-right::after {
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 54px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f57b20;
    bottom: -12px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

Here is my `HTML` Code

```
<div class="popups-right">
   <h3 style="color: #34213e;">ready to get fixed?</h3>
   <h3 style="color: #fff;">dont forget to include <br>this form in your order</h3>
   <h3 style="color: #fff;">simply click on this image <br>and start typing</h3>
   <h3 style="color: #fff;">please mark any areas you see <br>with pins. <span style="color: #34213e;">do not</span> use tape.</h3>
</div>
```

The font is not working as expected in `Chrome` and `Firefox` but working great on `Safari`. I am clueless about the issue. Please help.

This is how it looks in safari:
[image]

But this is how it is working on chrome and firefox:
[image]

The page is available live here: http://alterknit.staging.wpengine.com/packing-slip/

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated, and use console to debug you have errors there

Comment: @dippas I did not used <font> tag. Please see my code.

Comment: `<font color="#A7CD04">Alter Knit New York | 245 W 29th St, 9th Floor inside of MWS ProBeauty | New York, New York 10001  |  212-473-6363 (MEND)<br><div style="font-size:12px;">Copyright 2015 &copy; Knit NY LLC. All Rights Reserved.</div></font>`

Comment: I am talking about the code which I posted. @dippas

Comment: still that is deprecated.

Comment: @dippas ok that, help me with the issue i am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give to every heading in bubble a class, for example `.popups-right-title` & give styles

```
.popups-right-title {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Avoid using `!important` statement for declaring rules, so you will not have such problems in the future.

Comment: Please brief it more.

Comment: Sure, will let you know after trying.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this declaration: `font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;` does not work all together.

That second rendering uses some `serif` font but not `sans-serif` as you declared.

Use DOM inspector / debugging tools to discover other rules that override yours.

Comment: It was suggested by Google Fonts

Comment: What was suggested?

Comment: You missed the point. I am just saying that some other rule in your CSS is overriding that one of yours. To find that rule use debugging tools in browsers.

Comment: Ohhh!! Ok, sorry my bad.